# iOS app http requests fail after app comes back from background

Tags: ios

My (native) iOS app seems to work fine when running in the simulator or when running on a device while connected via USB. However, once the device is not connected to power, my app sometimes gets in a very bad state where http requests won't work anymore. I cannot even do a GET on google.com if I am in that state (the request times out). So far this issue has only occurred after the app came back from being backgrounded.

Any ideas on what could be the root cause or how to efficiently debug this would be much appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!